# Display running total textbox values' sum in the label

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to display the sum and the parentage of the performance values for the department vise filtered employees.

When I add values to the second row, the values add to the first row's sum.

Can some one help me to find the coding issue on my code??? Thanks.

This is my calculation view.

[image: This is my calculation view]

This is PHP code:

```
                      <tbody>

                        <?php

                        if(isset($_POST['filter'])){
                        $department = $_POST['department'];

                        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM employee_personal_details e INNER JOIN department_details a ON e.dep_id=a.dep_id WHERE dep_name = '$department' ";

                        $employees = mysqli_query($connection,$query1);

                        while ($list = mysqli_fetch_array($employees)) {



                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>".$list['emp_fullName']."</td>";          
                            echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"amount\" class=\"cal\" size=\"1\"></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"amount\" class=\"cal\" size=\"1\"></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"amount\" class=\"cal\" size=\"1\"></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"amount\" class=\"cal\" size=\"1\"></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"amount\" class=\"cal\" size=\"1\"></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"amount\" class=\"cal\" size=\"1\"></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"amount\" class=\"cal\" size=\"1\"></td>";
                            echo "<td id=\"sum\"></td>";
                            echo "<td id=\"prec\"></td>";


                        }
                    }
                    ?>

                </tbody>
```

and this is my javascript code:

```
          $(document).ready(function () {

              $(".cal").each(function () {
                   $(this).keyup(function () {
                    //Initialize total to 0
                        var total = 0;
                         $(".cal").each(function () {

                            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0 && this.value < 4) {
                              total += parseFloat(this.value);
                              precentage = (total/21)*100;
                         }
                    });

                    $('#sum').html(total);
                    $('#prec').html(precentage.toFixed(2));
               });
          });
     });
```

Comment: should follow the **DRY** method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.cal').keyup(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    var precentage = 0;
    $('.cal').each(function(){
      var curVal = parseFloat($(this).val());
      if(!isNaN(curVal) && curVal.length != 0 && curVal < 4){
        sum += curVal;
        precentage = (sum/21)*100;
      }
    });
    
    $('#sum').html(sum);
    $('#prec').html(precentage.toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="amount" class="cal" size="1">
<input type="text" name="amount" class="cal" size="1">
<input type="text" name="amount" class="cal" size="1">
<input type="text" name="amount" class="cal" size="1">
<input type="text" name="amount" class="cal" size="1">

SUM: <div id="sum"></div>
Precentage: <div id="prec"></div>
```

**Updated solution**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.cal').keyup(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    var precentage = 0;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').each(function(){
      var curVal = parseFloat($(this).find('.cal').val());
      if(!isNaN(curVal) && curVal.length != 0 && curVal < 4){
        sum += curVal;
        precentage = (sum/21)*100;
      }
    });

    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').find('.sum').html(sum);
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').find('.prec').html(precentage.toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount" class="cal" size="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount" class="cal" size="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount" class="cal" size="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount" class="cal" size="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount" class="cal" size="1"></td>
    <td>
      SUM: <div class="sum"></div>
      Precentage: <div class="prec"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount" class="cal" size="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount" class="cal" size="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount" class="cal" size="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount" class="cal" size="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount" class="cal" size="1"></td>
    <td>
      SUM: <div class="sum"></div>
      Precentage: <div class="prec"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: My problem is still there. When i add values to second row, they also add to the first row values. how to fix it??

Comment: @lak Welcome buddy :)